# Flutter: How to make a ListView transparent to pointer events (but not its non-transparent contents)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I have a `Scrollable` (`ListView` or any other) and it contains a transparent widget, say `Container(height:200)`. I can see through both the widget and the scrollable (in other words I can see the widgets behind the scrollable).

How can I be able to click through the transparent widget and the scrollable, so that I reach the widgets behind the scrollable?

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Container(height: 200), // Transparent.
    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 200),
    ],
);
```

Note, I cannot wrap the scrollable with `IgnorePointer`, because I still want to click the non-transparent widgets in the scrollable.

Comment: what did you mean by 'contains a transparent widget'? as children below scrollable or stacked below the Scrollable parent?

Comment: I mean the `Container(height: 200)` above.

Comment: what does 'that I reach the widgets behind the scrollable' mean?

Comment: Can you please give more details about what visual effect you are trying to achieve? I don't think you can tap through a transparent widget, but you can change your layout so that visually it remains the same and the widget you want to tap on is actually on top.

Comment: @Ovidiu Imagine you have a ListView in a Stack that covers the whole screen. The ListView is on top. You can drag it by the non-transparent widgets. And you can tap through the transparent ones.

Comment: Is there has any approach now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable solution I can think of is to have a `GestureDetector` on the transparent container, which will give you the global position of the taps:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTapUp: (TapUpDetails tapUpDetails) {
    print("onTapUp global: " + tapUpDetails.globalPosition.toString());
  },
```

And then add a `Key` to the widget behind the list, and use it to get the global position of the top left corner of the widget's rectangle, as well as the size of the widget, and use those to get the rectangle of the widget:

```
RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
Offset topLeftCorner = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
Size size = renderBox.size;
Rect rectangle = topLeftCorner & size;
```

If the background widget does not move, you can do it within `initState` on the very next frame using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` (the render object will be null if do it synchronously within `initState`) and save the `Rect` - otherwise you will have to recalculate it on every tap.

And then finally on each tap on the transparent container you can calculate whether the tap's position is within the boundaries of the background widget, and invoke the corresponding code:

```
// if tap is within boundaries of the background widget
if (rectangle.contains(tapUpDetails.globalPosition)) {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end I changed my requirements and don't need this anymore, so I won't have the chance to test your answer. But I think it could work, so I'll accept it. If one day I need this again I'll try to implement this and come back here to let you know.