# How to pass Taps to widgets below the top widget?

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement a very simple version of [Card Paginator Component](https://dribbble.com/shots/6160500-Card-Paginator-Component) (single card) in Flutter.

Here is an example of a basic demo I've created:

```dart
class CardComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 20.0,
          left: 20.0,
          child: 
          GestureDetector(
          // onTap should run while the text is visible on the screen
          // The text will become invisible when the Listview gest scrolled upwards
          onTap: (){print('text tapped');},
            child:
          Container(
          alignment:Alignment.topCenter,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        // This is fixed Text over which the card should scroll
        child: Text('Test Button')))),
        ListView(
          children: [
            //  This margin in first empty container pushes the whole card downward and makes the 'Test Button visible'
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0)),
            // This is where the scrolling card actually starts
            Container(color: Colors.cyan[100], height: 120.0, width: 20.0),
            Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 120.0, width: 20.0),
            Container(color: Colors.cyan[100], height: 120.0, width: 20.0),
            Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 120.0, width: 20.0),
            Container(color: Colors.cyan[100], height: 120.0, width: 20.0),
            Container(color: Colors.cyan, height: 120.0, width: 20.0),
          ]
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is, I'm unable to click the button when the card in not scrolled up. The fixed 'Test Button' is visible on the screen because of the empty dummy Container pushing the scrollable `ListView` downwards. Yet, since the `ListView` covers the full screen by default, hence the `onTap` never runs on tapping the button when it's visible.

[image]

If I surround the `ListView`/`SinglleChildScrollView` with `IgnorePointer` class, the whole scrolling behaviour stops and also any taps to the children of the ListView stops working which is not desired.

How to tap on the button (backward widget in Stack) while allowing scrolling/tapping in ListView? Or should I approach building [Card Paginator Component](https://dribbble.com/shots/6160500-Card-Paginator-Component) is some different way?

Comment: I think that the problem is that hit events are only passed to direct children. The `Positioned` is not a child of the `ListView` but `ListView` catches the hit event. You would need to find a way to pass the hit event to all children of your `Stack`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot that might help, but might cause problems when the card has scrolled up and someone clicks at a position where the button below is located. Also, couldn't find a way to pass hit events to all widgets. `AbsorbPointer` and `IgnorePointer` are two hit event based widgets I know of.

Comment: I think that you would need to implement custom logic that catches all hit events that arrive at the `Stack` and then manually decide which children of the `Stack` you want to pass it to. To be honest, if you are not familiar with `RenderObject`s ([`RenderProxyBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderProxyBox-class.html) in this case), it is not going to be a fun time for you trying to implement that quickly.

Comment: Okay. If you could please help out with even a basic solution, I'll try to pick up from there. Not familiar at all with `RenderObject`s.

Comment: can you also try this ? https://gist.github.com/Nash0x7E2/08acca529096d93f3df0f60f9c034056

Answer (score 5):

Potential duplicate of [Flutter: How to make a ListView transparent to pointer events (but not its non-transparent contents)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565123/flutter-how-to-make-a-listview-transparent-to-pointer-events-but-not-its-non-t)

You need to wrap your empty Container within the `ListView` with a `GestureDetector` overriding `onTapUp` so that you can capture the tap position on the screen:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTapUp: (TapUpDetails tapUpDetails) {
    print("onTapUp global: " + tapUpDetails.globalPosition.toString());
  },
```

You then need to get the rectangle of the widget behind the `ListView` that you want to tap on, by using that widget's key:

```
RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
Offset topLeftCorner = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
Size size = renderBox.size;
Rect rectangle = topLeftCorner & size;
```

And finally you can calculate whether the tap on the empty Container is within the rectangle of the widget behind, and at that point invoke your code as if you had a `GestureDetector` on the widget behind:

```
// if tap is within boundaries of the background widget
if (rectangle.contains(tapUpDetails.globalPosition)) {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: In step 2, has `_key` been previously defined as the key for the widget that we are checking? If so, you might consider adding that assignment statement at the beginning of step 2 for clarity. If not, how is `_key` defined?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want the fix bar height with button as per your current code but I can help you with the design as per your shared [Card Paginator Component](https://dribbble.com/shots/6160500-Card-Paginator-Component).

For that you can use `CustomScrollView` with `SliverAppBar`.

Here is the code

```
   CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          expandedHeight: 200,
          centerTitle: true,
          pinned: true,
          elevation: 0,
          flexibleSpace: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                        child: Image.asset("assets/user.png"),
                        maxRadius: 80,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(child: Text("Aakash Kumar", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,)),
          ),
        ),
        SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 150.0,
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              Container(color: Colors.red),
              Container(color: Colors.purple),
              Container(color: Colors.green),
              Container(color: Colors.orange),
              Container(color: Colors.yellow),
              Container(color: Colors.pink),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Hope this helps...