# Button underneath ListView in Stack won't receive onPressed Event

Tags: flutter

I have a Button that is underneath a ListView. See code below.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                 child: Text("Not Clickable"),
                  onPressed: () => print("Click!!!")
                )   
              ]
            )
          )
        ),
        ListView(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 400),
              child: Container(
                height: 5000,
                color: Colors.red
              )
            )
          ]
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

However the Button can't be pressed, it seems like the ListView receives the tap event and won't pass it through to the button underneath.

I can't use `IgnorePointer` on the ListView because the List also contains clickable widgets.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I found a hacky solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607716/9547658

Comment: I will leave this Question open for now, because this solution is not a great one and I'm wondering if meanwhile there is a more flutter-y solution

Comment: check this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450#issuecomment-575447316

Comment: did you solve it?