# Call IgonrePointer on parent but not child

Tags: flutter

I am developing my first Flutter app and have a question that I'm not finding an answer to:

I have a static fixed area at the bottom of my screen. Various buttons will be shown here depending on the page. I am using a stack to place this area on top of the rest of the screen, with the page content scrolling underneath my buttons.

[image]

The problem I am having is that the button(s) is/are sitting inside of a DecoratedBox, which in turn is sitting in front of my page content. This means that this box is blocking me from clicking on anything below the fixed area (like the button labelled "Programs" in the image)

I have come across the [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) and [AbsorbPointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) classes, which allows me to set the decorated box to ignore events. The problem here, however, is that it also causes the buttons in this fixed area to no longer react to events, as they are of course children of the box that I am applying the Igonre/AbsorbPointer classes to.

Is there a way to make the parent decorated box ignore events but have it's children react to them normally?

[image]

(blue area must ignore events, and the button must react to events)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link should help you solve your problem. I haven't tried it.

[Flutter: How to make a ListView transparent to pointer events (but not its non-transparent contents)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565123/flutter-how-to-make-a-listview-transparent-to-pointer-events-but-not-its-non-t)